# Showing series of a product converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that, given $\sum_i \mu(i) = 1$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_i \mu(i)q_n(i) \to 0$$ iff $$\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n(i)\to 0.$$

Is this a common lemma? How do I show this holds?

Comment: What are $\;\mu\;,\;q_n\;$ ...?

Comment: You can think of $\mu$ as a measure. $q_n(i)$ is a real valued function on $i$.

Comment: So the sums are finite? Independent of $\;n\;$ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [showing a condition implies convergence to invariant distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747784/showing-a-condition-implies-convergence-to-invariant-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

well that's untrue, say our domain is {1,2}  take $\mu(1)=0$ and $\mu(2)=1$ and take any function $q_n(i)$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n(1)= 1$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n(2)=0$$

Comment: Please replace $\to$ by $=$, twice.